# Specified cast is not valid. enum

Tags: c#, asp.net

whats wrong with this code, i try also `Enum.Parse` but didnt work.

```
public enum RoleNames  
{
    Administrator,
    [Description("Personnel Security")]
    PrsonalSecurity,
}

foreach (RoleNames roleName in arRoles) //<<<error
{
        if (IsCurrentUserInRole(roleName)) { return true; }
}
```

arRoles is ArrayList of RoleNames, which is passing as a parameters.

Comment: Any chance of describing your scenario? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Are you sure `arRoles` is a list of RoleNames? What is the exact type of `arRoles`?

Comment: if `arRoles` only contains `RoleNames`, then this code should work. But because it isn't generic, you won't get a compile time error.

Comment: arRoles is a RoleNames passing as a parameters, i am comparing to see what the user is passing and if that arRoles is in RoleNames. make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the rest of your code as the following example would work just fine:

```
public enum RoleNames   
{ 
    Administrator, 
    [Description("Personnel Security")] 
    PersonalSecurity
} 

RoleNames[] testEnumArray =
    { RoleNames.Administrator, RoleNames.PersonalSecurity };
foreach (RoleNames en in testEnumArray)
{
    // do something
}
```

Based on your error message, `arRoles` must not be an array of `RoleNames` since the cast is failing.

If you want to iterate over your enum definition you can use the following code:

```
foreach (RoleNames type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RoleNames)) 
{   
    // do something
}
```

Post your exact code.